# close current window by submenu item in ElectronJs

Tags: electron

I have two windows opened as you see in this picture:
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rnQzb.png)

I want to close smaller window by clicking on "close" submenu.

here's my code:

```
const addMenuTemplate = [
  {
    label:'file',
    submenu:[
      {
        label:'close',
        click(){
          //i dont know what to put here
        }
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

what should I do ?
I've already test `electron.remote.getCurrentWindow().close()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to close the current window, you don't have to write a custom `click` handler. The `close` role of MenuItem will handle it for you.

```js
  const template = [
    // ...
    {
      label: 'my-sub-menu',
      submenu: [
        { role: 'close' },
        { role: 'quit' },
      ]
    }
    // ...
  ]
```

See a [live example Gist](https://gist.github.com/3da98e3ac483a75eb8f36a22c6a07d28) openable in [Electron Fiddle](https://www.electronjs.org/fiddle).

Answer (score 0):

If you have the window stored in a variable you can use [`win.close()`](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/browser-window#winclose).

And it will close the window.